# Open source web browser for iPhone, for in app browsing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, open-source

I'm building some kind of a twitter client, but when there's a link to web in a tweet, I want to be able to display it in my app without jumping to Safari.

Is there any open source project to do it? I know I can use UIWebView, but I want to get all the features like back button, forward button, refresh, progress bar, etc.

Comment: Section 2.17 of the App Store Review Guidelines say that you **must** use webkit (i.e. UIWebView) to browse. If you don't, you risk getting your app rejected.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was indeed looking for a webkit implementation, but from the answer it seems that I just have to make it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the features that you want are fairly trivial to implement using a `UIWebView` and a class that implements the [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate) protocol.  Back, forward, stop, and refresh are all very easy, the only thing you can't get is an *accurate* progress bar.  But you can detect when a page is loading and throw up a spinner or other generic loading graphic.

If you place a `UIToolbar` above your `UIWebView` with the appropriate icons on it and enable/disable/update them according to the messages that get passed to your `UIWebViewDelegate` implementation you can easily get an in-app experience that very nearly approximates that of a full-fledged browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought I would be able to save a few hours of work, but now that you say it like that, I think it'll be a good exercise for me anyway.

Comment: @the_great_monkey - Honestly, I can't see how it wouldn't take you far longer to incorporate some random open source browser into your project than hooking up a few UI elements and delegate callbacks.  UIWebView has its flaws, but difficulty of integration with an application is not one of them.